# Chrome Incognito Data - Crashed system - Retrieve of information from temp files?

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy, recovery, private-browsing

I've done I believe quite a research on the internet about it, and there is not much information even about just information about how does exactly Chrome Incognito works in the sense of where does Chrome stores it's incognito data about open tabs, etc.

In short it seems plausible that this data is stored somewhere in ...\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default Obviously every time an incognito session is closed, the files are also being deleted or edited, however I suspect that in the rare case of system failure(for example due to power cut-off) this data won't be deleted until next opening of Chrome.

I was therefore wondering if anyone knows or could hint me where to search for this data about which tabs were opened in this crashed incognito session, because I am clueless and not that much technical in this area.

Maybe this data is indeed stored in some obvious place, but it's inaccessible anyway due to it being maybe a database file?

Comment: Isn't the entire idea of Incognito mode that it stores no trace of where you went?

Comment: @Tetsujin Sure, but the data must be stored somewhere for the time when the incognito mode is working and there should be a way to see that data. I don't see conflict in that.

Comment: Ideally, it would be stored in RAM, otherwise it could be intercepted by a bad actor.